# data empty using ReportUserAction component

Tags: react-admin

I'm using the following code to create an action on a Edit View:

```
const PostEditActions = ({ basePath, data, resource }) => (
<CardActions>
    <ReportUserAction record={data} />
</CardActions>
);

export const UserEdit = (props) => (
<Edit title="Modify user parameters" actions={<PostEditActions />} {...props}>
....
```

In ReportUserAction component I receive data= undefined, but I don't know why. The edit view has data:

```
{"data":{"locale":"en","status":"enabled","facebookId":"XXXXX","createdAt":"2016-06-15T20:21:47.000Z",...
```

And I can access to other variables such as basePath and Resource.
How can I pass data with the correct information?

Thanks